# Trying to make a encryption program, but it won't let me add 2 variables for one index?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I have been programming an encryption program as my friend and I like cryptography. I'm planning to go quite far with this program, and everythings been going great until I hit this little snag. For some reason, I cannot add two variables together to make an index for a list, and when I run it it returns the following error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`. 
Here is the code:

```
def random_key():  # Creates a function called randomKey; runs if the user chose 'random key' for encryption option.
encryption_key = []  # Empty list where the encryption key will be stored.
encrypted_word = []
b = []

main_root = Tk()  # Creates a window.
for x in range(0, len(content)):  # This for loop will run to create the random encryption key.
    encryption_key.append(random.randrange(0, len(content)))  # Creates random numbers for the encryption key.

for index in range(0, len(content)):  # Creates a index that is the length of the users input.
    if content[index] in alphabet:  # If the users input with the index is in the alphabet,
        # Then it will use the alphabet dictionary to get the place value of the character in content,
        b.append(alphabetDict[content[index]])

for x in b:
    int(x)
    encrypted_word.append(alphabet[x+encryption_key])
```

Ignore the half commenting and weird variable names (such as 'b'), I've been trying to experiment and will fix those later.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `encryption_key` is a list, you cannot do `x+encryption_key`, it makes no sense.

Comment: Realised that the function isn't indented correctly; it's fine in the original code.

Comment: @1615903 Well, I'm an idiot.

Comment: please keep in mind... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own